# How to validate NIC Number using Oracle Forms?

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

A National Identity Card number looks like this: `878552361V`.

It contains 9 digits and a capital `'V'` or `'X'` at the end.

How to validate it using *Oracle Forms 11g* library?

Comment: `regexp_like(<column_name>, '\d+{9}(X|V)')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function in your library as below:

```
FUNCTION validate_nid (p_nid IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN BOOLEAN
IS
   v   NUMBER;
   e EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   IF LENGTH (p_nid) > 10
   THEN
      RAISE e;
   END IF;

   -- check if first 8 are alpa
   v := SUBSTR (p_nid, 1, 9);

   IF SUBSTR (p_nid, 10, 1) != 'V' Or
       SUBSTR (p_nid, 10, 1) != 'X'
   THEN
      RAISE e;
   END IF;

   RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN e
   THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
END;
```

And call this function in when-validate-item trigger as following:

```
if not validate_nid('878552361V') then
  raise form_trigger_failure;
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (regexp_substr('876963256V','^[0-9]{9}[vV|xX]$')) is null then 
         raise form_trigger_failure;
    end if;
```